# Is there an upper limit to the number of commits a git repository can handle?

Tags: git, commit, rebase

I'm wondering if there's an upper limit to the number of commits that a git repository can handle.

In a solo project I'm working on right now, I've been coding locally, committing/pushing changes in git, then pulling the changes on my development server.

I treat this as an easier alternative to working locally and uploading changes via FTP... Fortunately/Unfortunately it's such an easy workflow that I sometimes go through *many* edit/commit/push/pull/browser-refresh cycles while coding.

I'm wondering if this is going to turn around and bite me somewhere down the line.  If it's likely to be a problem, I'm wondering how I can avoid that trouble ... It seems like a rebase might be the way to go, especially since I won't have to worry about conflicting branches etc.

Comment: git scales to the entire linux kernel (that is what it was made for). So unless you have hundreds of MB of code with a decade of commits, don't worry aboutit.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Well the "upper limit" would likely be the point at which a SHA1 collision occurs, but since the SHAs are 40 hexadecimal digits long (16^40 ~ 1.4x10^48 possibilities), it's so close to zero possibility that it's not even funny. So there's roughly a zero percent chance you'll have any problems for at least the next several millennia.

Hyperbolic Example (just for fun): 1 commit/minute (just changing one file -> three new SHAs used (file, commit, tree) = 3 new shas used / minute = ... = 1.6M shas used / year = 1.6 Billion shahs / millennia = 1x10^-37 **%** used each millenia... (at 1000 files/commmit/min, it's still 3.6x10^-35%)

That being said, if you want to clean up your history, squashing them down with rebase is probably your best bet. Just make sure you understand the implications if you've shared the repo publicly at all.

You might also want to garbage collect after rebasing to free up some space (make sure the rebase worked right first, though, and you might need to tell it to collect everything or it will, by default, not collect anything newer than two-weeks old).

Comment: but it is still possible 
Just like GUID and UUID

Comment: ok i understand this point. but in the concrete git implementation: is there maybe a place like `long amount=Count(GetCommitsWithCertainProperties(x,y))` where the operation fails if there are more than 2^32 commits?

Comment: Also, whenever it comes to collisions, don't forget about the birthday paradox. But even in case of a collision, when you retry the commit, the timestamp will be different and so will the hash be. So even when collisions occur, you can still commit and everything should keep working.

Comment: Collision probability for a 160-bit hash is 6σ (i.e. 1e-7) after at least 1e21 commits, according to [this calculator](https://kevingal.com/apps/collision.html).

Comment: The Linux kernel apparently passed 1M (1e6) commits in 2020. I'm curious how many _total_ commits are in GitHub, across _all repos_... My example above indicates 1.6B (1.6e9) commits in _1000 years_. That hyperbolic example is still quite a ways from 1e21.
Yes, the birthday paradox means it's not a raw percentage. The calculations above don't show the probability of _collision_, just the number of hashes calculated (/"used"). The end result is the same - don't worry about collisions.

Answer (score 7):

I'm pretty sure you don't have to worry at all :)

Git is using SHA-1 hash in order to check files, the probability of having an hash conflict is near zero. So have fun !!

I personally did around 30 commits a day without issue.

But avoid versioning binaries files :) it's really heavy for what it is.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is no strong limit to the number of commits git can handle, only what you can personally digest. With larger projects and multiple developers, you'll see more activity than you would ever generate on your own.

You can keep a secondary branch that you merge to every week if you wish, but git will never care about how many commits you have. Go crazy as long as you can understand what you're doing. You can always diff several commits back or use tools like bisect to figure out history problems.