# Clarification on Github Merged pull requests

Tags: git, github

I've just merged a PR from within github. The total number of commits in the branch is 1339. We have a hook into slack and the message we received says that only 1000 commits were merged.

Is this a rounding issue? or is this an actual issue and 300+ commits weren't merged. I cant see how there would be an upper limit on commits when merging.

Can someone shed some light please?

Comment: I would say that this is a problem with the slackbot. You can check on github if any commits are missing. There isn't any limit on git. Also, something seems off with your strategy if you have that many commits on a branch. Check also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339221/is-there-an-upper-limit-to-the-number-of-commits-a-git-repository-can-handle

Comment: Does your "total number of commits in the branch" refer to commits *only* on this branch? Because if you did a `git rev-list --count` what you have is the total number of commits since initial commit. Sorry to ask, but it'll be good to rule that out.

Comment: hi @RaulRene you're not wrong, it's a 6 month project though and we needed to branch off and not effect master till the work was completed.

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks for that i'll check that command and see what it does :)

Comment: @RaulRene i think you're right: re Slackbot. Github seems legit on it all. I saw the discrepency and was a little worried