# git status shows untouched files as modified, and git diff cannot hash them

Tags: git, doxygen

Ubuntu 16.04, git version 2.7.4

I have been developing some code locally that is also hosted remotely.
Today, and a few other times earlier occasionally, what follows happens.
The other times it disappeared after just waiting sceptically, but now it seems to be persistent.

#### Step 1, pass: synchronize current branch with remote

> git pull
>   Already up-to-date.

#### Step 2, fail: check status and new modified files show up out of the blue

> git status
>
> On branch [mybranch]
>   Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/[mybranch]'.
>   Changes not staged for commit:
>   (use "git add ..." to update what will be committed)
>   (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory)
>
> **some 30+ files are given as modified, even though I don't quite think they have been changed**

(After reboot they have become 15, erratically. 
After another reboot, 3. 
Take note: no action on the files)

#### Step 3: inquiry what the difference would be

Probing the situation with a couple of files, I get

> git diff ../../[directory]/[directory]/[file].md5
>   **error: short read No such file or directory**
>   **error: [directory]/[directory]/[file].md5: failed to insert into database**
>   fatal: cannot hash [directory]/[directory]/[file].md5

#### Research

Thinking of [Git shows all files as modified after changing file permission](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27056788/5459638), I don't think to have changed permissions any recently. Those files are quite fossilised.

#### Questions

What is the possible cause of this situation, and how to prevent that this happens again?

And why would it self-heal automagically at times, and persist at others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 16.04, git version 2.7.4, Doxygen 1.8.12

#### Diagnose

The offending files were elements of a Doxygen documentation and were stored in a single directory of 507M and 19,415 files. 
Probably this confused the book-keeping in git,
my first assumption.

#### Cure

Doxygen has an option in the configuration file to distribute files over different directories, actually with a tree structure similar way to how git does

> # If the CREATE_SUBDIRS tag is set to YES then doxygen will create 4096 sub-
>   # directories (in 2 levels) under the output directory of each output format and
>   # will distribute the generated files over these directories. Enabling this
>   # option can be useful when feeding doxygen a huge amount of source files, where
>   # putting all generated files in the same directory would otherwise causes
>   # performance problems for the file system.
>   # The default value is: **NO**.
>
> CREATE_SUBDIRS         = **YES**

I have set this to yes, and cycled over

```
git status; git add .; git commit -m ...; git push
```

a couple of times until I got:

> git status
>       On branch [mybranch]
>       Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/[mybranch]'.
>       nothing to commit, working directory clean

which sorts out the problem in Step 2 above.

#### Trivia

For the curious reader I found these other posts which *kind of* corroborated my approach, at least give me some clues that it was worth trying:

- [Is there an upper limit to the number of commits a git repository can handle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339221/is-there-an-upper-limit-to-the-number-of-commits-a-git-repository-can-handle)
- https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301400/why-is-the-git-git-objects-folder-subdivided-in-many-sha-prefix-folders

Any expert/experienced that wish to raise the quality of this answer, be my guest.